# While Searching for a key in a map in C++ STL, gives the following error

Tags: c++, stl, maps

I have a created a Map with key as string type and the associated value stored in vector. Now I have a string and need to check if the each of the character in the string is present as a key in the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   map<string, vector<string>> umap;
   umap["1"] = {"a","b","c"};
   umap["2"] = {"d","e","f"};
   string s = "23";
   for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
      if(umap.find(s[i]) != umap.end()) 
          cout<<"Present"<<endl;
      else
          cout<<"Not Present"<<endl;
      }
}
```

Error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)’
         if(umap.find(s[i]) != umap.end())
```

Comment: `s[i]` is not an `std::string`, but a `char`.

Comment: try `umap.find(s.substr(i, 1))`...

Answer (score 4):

The error is maybe a bit cryptic. Lets translate it into something human readable.

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::find(__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&)’
         if(umap.find(s[i]) != umap.end())
```

First `std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>` is a complicated way to denote a `std::string`. Then `__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<char> >::value_type&` is an even more complicated way to denote the return type of `s[i]` which is actually just `char&`. Putting this together we get

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string> >::find(char&)’
         if(umap.find(s[i]) != umap.end())
```

I hope now you can see that the error complains that there is no overload of `find` that would take a `char&` as parameter.

Instead you should pass a `std::string`, eg via `s.substr(i,1)`.